# Why there is a white space in the right side when using wallpaper & polyglossia in TexLive 2013

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, bidi, wallpaper

when I use  wallpaper & polyglossia there is a white space in the right side of the page. Please test this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra,url,amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}
test
\ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{1.jpeg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TL13? That has not been released yet.

Comment: @daleif I am using pretest TL 13 version. However, in TexLive 2012 the white space in the left side.

Comment: It seems that it is bidi bug : http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2013-June/024432.html

Comment: @persian-tex-group any help in this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug already made known to the package developer